# Creating reusable code modules (e.g. C++ style classes, headers) in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In C++, you can create usable code modules by creating a class, and giving out header and implementation files to the developers who want to use your class.

I want to do this in C# but I have little experience with the C# language. Basically I need to create a class that can be reused by another C# programmer in Visual Studio 2010. I know that referencing DLLs is one way to use other peoples' classes. Do I need to create a DLL to achieve what I want to accomplish? Or are there other, better ways?

For example, let's say I create a Cow class that can "moo". In C++, someone who uses my class would just include Cow.h, instantiate a Cow object myCow, and then call myCow.moo(). How can I achieve this simple task in C#?

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: There is little difference between C++ and C# regarding your requirements. You can give the source  or build an assembly (dll) and give it. Just like C++.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I have a further question: my supervisor said that he wanted me to create a "container class" in C# for this purpose. If I'm not mistaken, I thought that container classes are a C++ thing? Or is he just mistakenly using the term?

Comment: We will not be able to answer what someone wants you to do... But in general "container class" is some class that can contain other object irrespective of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just create `Class Library` project and share the resulted dll's.

Other developers will just need to add a reference to your dll and after that they're free to use any public objects from your library.

Comment: Ah, so that is how one creates reusable classes in C#! I've never created this type of VS project before, thanks.

Comment: @Terribad: yep, that is a type of project that doesn't have executable as a result, just dll assemblies. Btw, you can create regular executable console application and refer to it too ;-)

Comment: Reference to a console application?! I wonder how that works :/

Comment: @Terribad: in the same way like reference to dll ))

Answer (score 0):

It is the standard to create a dll to distribute reusable code.

You could look into old school COM objects, but I would steer clear of them and just use a well organized class library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. DLL it is, then.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can always share your source files, but the recommended .Net way of distributing reusable code is though dlls. This allows developers using any .Net language to use your code (they don't have to use the same language as your project).

It also makes it easier to maintain the project. If you share source code then it will likely be more difficult to distribute updates than if you just needed to update a single dll. If you have multiple projects referencing the same dll, they can all reference it from the same location and whenever the dll is updated, all the projects that use it will automatically use the updated dll the next time they compile the project. You can also update the dll without having to recompile the projects that use it (though you can't change the names/signatures of anything that is being used by the project).

Comment: Thanks for the information, Brian. I gather that DLLs are the standard way of doing this. DLL it is, then.